# Python Traversing a filesystem. Strange Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to traverse a directory. Below is the code:

```
file_list = []
    os.chdir(self.config.Root_Directory_Path())
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
        file_list.extend( join(root,f) for f in files )
    file_sorted = sorted(file_list)
    f = open(self.config.Client_Local_Status(),'wb')        
    for file in file_sorted:
        print(file + "|" + str(os.path.getmtime(file)) + "\n")            
    f.close()
```

Firstly, I traverse the tree, then sort it and then print it. But I get the below error while traversing. I am very sure that the file exist, but not able to figure out the reason for error. PLEASE HELP ME FIGURE OUT REASON FOR ERROR AND HENCE FIX IT.

Below is the output.

Output:

```
.\Drivers\Intel Drivers\Applications\Software\Applications\Wave_Embassy_Trust_Suite\EMBASSY Security Center\program files\Wave Systems Corp\EMBASSY Security Center\plugins\cpm.scp\webinterface\ru\js\HelpMessages.js|1229488128.0

.\Drivers\Intel Drivers\Applications\Software\Applications\Wave_Embassy_Trust_Suite\EMBASSY Security Center\program files\Wave Systems Corp\EMBASSY Security Center\plugins\cpm.scp\webinterface\ru\js\Strings.js|1229488128.0
```

After printing lot of file names successfully, the code fails for one particular file as shown below:

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SyncClientRK\SyncClientRK.py", line 183, in <module>
    SyncClientRK()
  File "C:\SyncClientRK\SyncClientRK.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.getStatus()
  File "C:\SyncClientRK\SyncClientRK.py", line 38, in getStatus
    self.generateLocalStatus()
  File "C:\SyncClientRK\SyncClientRK.py", line 53, in generateLocalStatus
    print(file + "|" + str(os.path.getmtime(file)) + "\n")
  File "C:\Python33\lib\genericpath.py", line 54, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '.\\Drivers\\Intel Drivers\\Applications\\Software\\Applications\\Wave_Embassy_Trust_Suite\\EMBASSY Security Center\\program files\\Wave Systems Corp\\EMBASSY Security Center\\plugins\\cpm.scp\\webinterface\\zh-CHS\\AccessingToolkit.htm'
```

Please notice that the file is fetched in the loop and is printed, but os.path.getmtime is throwing an error that will not found. Not able to understand why and how to fix this.

Comment: I see this is an HTML file. Have you tried opening that in your browser to see if it actually exists? My guess is it might have existed when you called `os.walk` and to have been deleted by the time you got to check its modification time.

Comment: @reseter Certainly it is an HTML file. I opened it with notepad and also browser and I see html content within it. It also has some Chinese in it. But I believe that should also not matter, as I am not reading the contents with in it. It is not deleted for sure because I am not deleting it. I can see the file all the time. Below traversing and also after traversing. Anymore guesses please?

Comment: You should definitely catch errors due to vanished files.

Comment: @Alfe, how can a file vanish? I agree to put a catch, but how will I end up not getting the exception at all, which is my goal. I am seeing it all the time... Before traversal and also after traversal. I am traversing a folder in my filesystem. No other process is accessing this folder except my python code. Thanks

Comment: Maybe in your case it didn't, okay.  How about inserting a `print os.path.exists(file)` before printing the mtime?  What does this print, False or True?  And why do you open `f` when you're doing nothing with it besides closing it again? ;-)

Comment: @Alfe, I will try the print os.path.exists now. To answer to other part of your question, I am using the file pointed by f in some other function later in my program to read and do a particular task. So no worries about f. I will try os.path.exists and reply back soon... Thanks

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use better names, btw.  I propose `file_names_sorted` instead of `file_sorted` and `file_name` instead of `file`.  Besides that `file` is already a builtin type you this way shadow (which can lead to hard bugs), it also is not the same as a file name.  But that's just a hint; would have helped me understand your code faster.

Comment: @Alfe, as per your suggestion, I put if os.path.exists: before print os.path.getmtime and as you guesses, the line with file AccessingToolkit.htm got skipped. But I am not undestand why? I can see the file all the time. Before and after traversal. So what might be the reason? Appreciate your efforts brother.

Comment: @Alfre thanks for suggestion, I would certainly rename . Please further help me understand, why, why, and why is this file not accessible. Why am I getting FileNotFound. It exists all the time for sure no doubt about it

Comment: Strange characters in the file name maybe?  Obviously `os.walk` returns something you cann access later; that should not happen, but it does.  Has to be something quirky, could have to do with Windows file systems, file name handling etc.  Print the name when it does not exist, use repr(file_name), and see if you can find strange characters inside.  More likely that something else is fiddling in, but that's currently my best guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a 220 character long filename, starting in a local directory. Assuming that the local directory has a path that is longer than 40 characters, you are hitting an old Windows limit of paths that are longer than 260 characters.

Not all ways of handling files in Windows has this limit, but it may be that this is the problem here. If there are filenames in your list that is even longer, then this is clearly not the problem, but that's what I would look into first.

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath

Comment: After the strange-character-stuff that would have been my second guess ;-)  But is there really a limit of 260 characters??  That's ridiculously short (and a very peculiar number).  Unless you are on a CD or similar.

Comment: Yes, strange character was also my first guess, but I can't see any non-ascii characters in his example path. Yes, there is a limit of 260 characters. Yes, that's ridiculously short, but that's Windows! I added a link to a way that might be a workaround, I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I agree to both Alfre and Lennart Regebro. Give me a moment, let me start counting and also look for any special characters. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @LennartRegebro . Wonderful answer. It is the length that is stopping me. I put the . folder in C:\ and it worked fine because the length was much smaller. I am curious to understand the workaround. I am reading the link. Can you also please elaborate in your words here. Thanks a million

Comment: @Alfre I would like to thank you and also request you to post your ideas of strange characters being present. In fact there were strange characters, in other test cases , I solved them by encoding with utf-8 format. However, I request you to post this solution also as an answer. I would love you up vote it. Thanks...

Comment: @LennartRegebro if you find this question interesting, please upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Strange characters in the file name maybe? Obviously `os.walk` returns something you cannot access later; that should not happen, but it does. Has to be something quirky, could have to do with Windows file systems, file name handling etc.  Print the name when it does not exist, use `repr(file_name)`, and see if you can find strange characters inside.  More likely that something else is fiddling in, but that's currently my best guess.